# selecting equal amount from each given condition in a query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$tags = explode(',' , $tags );
$query = " select * from table where 1=2  ";

foreach($tags as $tag )
$query .= " || `tags` = '$tag' ";

$query .=" order by id desc limit 3 ";
```

so lets say

```
$tags = array( a , b ,c );
```

and we have many rows with  `a , b , c` as tag in database

now if the last 3 rows in database have `tag=a` then this query will return these 3 rows .

so i'll get 3 `a` tags and here is the problem i want to select equal amount of each given tag from db .. in this example `a , b ,c`  not 3 `a` .

and here is the tricky part .... database may only have a , b tags .... in this case i want 2 `a` and 1 `b` ... or 1 `a` and 2 `b`

is there anyway to do this ?

Comment: Consider providing sample data and the desired result as a set of DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle